# How to return negative value from function?

Tags: c++, function

Below is the code snippet of reversing a positive of a negative number.But it always returning positive number of all negative numbers.If anyone know what's happening please do let me know.

code:

```
int reverse(int x){
    int sub=0;
    if(x<0){
        while (x!=0){
        sub = sub*10 + x%10;
        x = x/10;
        }
        return (sub * -1);
    }
    else{
        while (x!=0)
        {
            sub = sub*10 + x%10;
            x = x/10;
        }
        return sub;
    }
    
}

int main(){
    int x = -123;
    cout<<reverse(x);
    cout<<c;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You don't need two clauses.  The second part of the `if` statement will work for positive or negative values.

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well:

```
return (sub * -1);
```

Sub will be `-321` at this time. And `-321 * -1 = 321`.

Comment: Could also be just `-sub`.

Answer (score 0):

The usual approach is to write code that handles non-negative numbers, and convert negative numbers to positive:

```
bool neg = false;
if (x < 0) {
    neg = true;
    x = -x;
}

// code to reverse the digits goes here

if (neg)
    x = -x;
```

or, if you like recursive functions:

```
int reverse(int x) {
    if (x < 0)
        return -reverse(-x);

    // code to reverse the digits goes here

    return whatever;
}
```